# Color functional groups in chemfig syntax

Tags: color, best-practices, chemfig

I want to color simple functional groups in organic molecules using the `chemfig` package. I've come up with a solution that achieves what I want (MWE), but I find it *very* cumbersome. I thought it could be possible to wrap an entire group in one single `color`-statement. [This question about colouring the background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123967/fill-the-background-of-functional-groups-in-chemfig) of a group of atoms in `chemfig` also gives a neat graphical emphasis of a group of atoms.

Is my solution, and the solution to the question above, the easiest way to colour or mark groups of atoms (including bonds) in `chemfig`? Just now, I don't have a need to easily reproduce loads of coloured functional groups, but I would like to know if there are easier ways to solve this problem without predefining macros for each group.

I believe I understand that the underlying problem is the way `chemfig` uses Ti*k*Z nodes to draw the structures, but I can't help to think that there should be a way to define some color environment that applies to all the Ti*k*Z nodes made by `chemfig`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-{\color{blue}C}(=[1,,,,blue] {\color{blue}O})(-[7,,,,blue] {\color{blue}OH})}
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

Comment: I don't really have an answer but I'd probably really define macros or submols (depending on the wanted functionality)

Comment: I believe that what you did is the best you can do in chemfig at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Relate to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100653/chemfig-colour-entire-atom-or-section-of-atom/156591#156591).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \def\RED{\gdef\printatom##1{\color{red}\ensuremath{\mathrm{##1}}}}
    \def\BLACK{\gdef\printatom##1{\color{black}\ensuremath{\mathrm{##1}}}}
    \noindent
    \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[,,,,draw=none]\RED)([,,,,,red]-[,,,,black]C(=[1]O)(-[7]OH))}\BLACK \\[1cm]
    \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-C(=[1]O)(-[7]OH))}
\end{document}
```

Where

- `[,,,,red]` is to set the color of bonds within COOH.
- `[,,,,black]` is to set the color of bond between C2H5 and COOH.
- `(-[,,,,draw=none]\RED)` is to create an ad hoc atom to change the color.

  - you can change the color anywhere, but sometimes it may cause bad spacing/positioning.
  - (e.g. `chemfig` reads `\RED COOH` as five atoms, with the first atom having zero width.)